# Rewrite a value in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, replace

I have a script that makes a list of list that represent a playground:

```
#Script:
import math
listx=[]
List=[]
N_M=input("Enter N M: ").split()
n=int(N_M[0])
m=int(N_M[1])
for i in range(m):
    listx+=[0]
for i in range(n):
    List.append(listx)
print(List)

#Example of playground for M=3 and N=3:
[0,0,0] 
[0,0,0] 
[0,0,0]
```

Then I want to change a certain place to 1

```
List[0][1]=1
```

That should (if I understand it correctly) change it to:

```
[0,1,0]
[0,0,0] 
[0,0,0]
```

But instead it changes every list to:

```
[0,1,0]
[0,1,0] 
[0,1,0]
```

Please help!
Thank you very much in advise!

Comment: You want `List.append(listx.copy())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bit:

```
for i in range(n):
    List.append(listx)
```

Adds the same list (`listx`) to `List` three times. So when you change it one place, all references change, because they are all pointing to the same list.

Also, as a side note: don't name variables `List` with a capital, because that makes others (and software) think it's a class. And the name `list` is of course even worse, because that would be shadowing the type `list`. Come up with names that are meaningful and not overly generic - like `playground`.

A more efficient way of creating an `n` x `m` list:

```
playground = [[0] * m for _ in range(n)]
```

The bit `[0] * m` creates a list with `m` zeroes; this works because a number isn't referenced like a list and the zeroes won't be copies of the same variable.

The `for _ in range(n)` causes the resulting list to be filled with `n` of those lists. The `_` just means you're not doing anything with the number from the `range()`, it's only there for a number of repetitions and the `for` loop needs something in that place, either a variable or the `_` "don't care".

Answer (score 1):

In the second for-loop you are appending the *same* list to `List` n-times over.

```
for i in range(n):
    List.append(listx)
```

You need to make copies of `listx` & use those inside `List`. Like this:

```
for i in range(n):
    List.append(listx[::])
```

`listx[::]` makes a copy of `listx` to use.

Answer (score 0):

In your second for loop you are appending the same list many times, you are appending a "view/reference" not the actual list, so in your second four you have to append a copy of the `listx`, for this you can use :

- `list(listx)`
- `listx[::]`
- `listx.copy()`

Is like you want to buy apples, but you have only one and other 3 pictures of the first apple, you can' say you have 4 apples